# Adding Bootstrap carousel component

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Very simple question about adding the Bootstrap carousel component... I am using the code below to add a simple picture/carousel section to my website. [Here is the page from Bootstrap where I got it.](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#slides-only) When I open this, it just loads all the images statically on the page as if I just added them normally.

```
    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/hotyellowpinkpop.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/pinkyellowater.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="img/purpleyellowmoons.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have bootstrap js files present and linked in the  of the html document. What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're using `.carousel-item` where it should be `.item`. You can see an example here https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_EqZzf-l7OCg/TNmdtcyGBZI/AAAAAAAAAD8/KD5Y23c24go/s1600/homer-simpson-1280x1024.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://futurism.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/neildegrassetyson.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of things you need to check for:

- Is bootstrap fully loaded?

  - .js and .css files
- Have you initilized the corousel?

  - here's the jQuery for initializing: `$('.carousel').carousel()`

If you've done those things, let us know and maybe give us a link to the page you're having trouble with, or reproduce it for us on CodePen or JSFiddle or the like.